# Implementing velocity verlet algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm

I've used the following formulae to implement the velocity verlet algorithm (written here in a sort of pseudo code):

```
time+=timeStep;
newPosition+=timeStep*(velocity+acceleration*timeStep*0.5);

newA = Force/mass, force is a function of newPosition

v+= 0.5*timeStep*(newA-acceleration);
```

This doesn't work! newA-acceleration is stupidly small. Am I using the wrong formulae? Or does the velocity verlet algorithm just not work well for small timeSteps (I was using 2 seconds)?

(Sorry if this is in the wrong place by the way, didn't know where else to put it)

Comment: Stupid, stupid, stupid. newA+acceleration! Add not subtract! Sorry. Solved it.

Comment: You may answer your own question - there even is a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for it.

Answer (score 2):

Should be newA + acceleration, not newA-acceleration. Oops!